# GetAddrInfoW does not return IPv6 addresses?

Tags: winapi, winsock

When I use `nslookup` for `"google.com"` I get the following:

```
Addresses:  2607:f8b0:400a:801::1001
          173.194.33.32
          173.194.33.36
          173.194.33.34
          173.194.33.37
          173.194.33.33
          173.194.33.46
          173.194.33.39
          173.194.33.41
          173.194.33.38
          173.194.33.40
          173.194.33.35
```

However when I call `GetAddrInfoW` and pass it `L"google.com"` I get the following:

```
173.194.33.41
173.194.33.39
173.194.33.46
173.194.33.33
173.194.33.37
173.194.33.38
173.194.33.40
173.194.33.34
173.194.33.35
173.194.33.36
173.194.33.32
```

Where'd the IPv6 address go?

**Edit:** If I do the same lookup with the same code for `"localhost"` the output is:

```
0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001
127.0.0.1
```

Which is even more of a head scratcher.

Comment: Are you specifying an `ADDRINFOW` in the `pHints` parameter? If so, are you setting its `ai_family` field to `AF_INET`, `AF_INET6` or `AF_UNSPEC`? If not, it defaults to `AF_UNSPEC`.

Comment: No I'm not.  The documentation leads me to believe that it defaults to `AF_UNSPEC` as you said, and that means that the caller can handle either IPv4 or IPv6.  Interesting to note -- I'll add this to the OP -- but looking up `localhost` yields `::1` as one of the responses (`127.0.0.1` being the other)...

Comment: Can you show your actual code?